# How can i catch the output of a command and send it to a function if it fails?

Tags: mysql, bash

I'm not using set -e in my shell script, i'm handling each specific error with a function (event). In this particular case i'm trying to (insert a database and) catch any errors from mysql if it fails. Then send it straight into my event function so i can store it in a logfile.

```
mysql $schema < 'structure_dump.sql' || event "8" "$schema structure insert failed:"
```

I thought that output would be caught by doing this, but my error variable appears empty when this fails even though i'm still getting the mysql error message on my screen.

```
err=$(mysql $schema < 'structure_dump.sql') || event "8" "$schema structure insert failed: $err"
```

Is it possible to do this or am i thinking about it in the wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL should be reporting errors on `stderr` but you are only capturing `stdout`. Redirect `stderr` (descriptor 2) to `stdout` (descriptor 1)

I believe this should work for you:

```
# Push stderr into stdout in your output capture
err=$(mysql $schema < 'structure_dump.sql' 2>&1) || event "8" "$schema structure insert failed: $err"
```